# break loop command in .draggable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for loop, and an if statement inside the for loop with a break command.  All of this is in a .draggable function.  The break, seems to prevent the .draggable from rerunning the loop again when my mousemoves.  I want the loop to break when it hits the right value, but then run again from the beggining as I keep dragging.

the for loop is something like this:

```
for (i=1; i < 30, i +=1) {
 if (myvariable == i) {
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the full `draggable` call?

Comment: This loop as given is not syntactically valid: `i < 30, i += 1` -- should have a semicolon instead of a comma.

Comment: Have you tried just setting `i=30` inside the if statement instead of the break.  This should accomplish the same task without using the break if it is that that is screwing things up.